# Поиск по регулярному выражению SQL PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

В базе новостей ID категорий хранится в таком виде 3,7,15
Запрос:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, title FROM news WHERE cat_id REGEXP '[[:<:]]?,' ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->execute(["7"]);
```

В результате достаются только новости, ID которых 7, (с запятой), а если cat_id имеет только 7, то не достается запись.

Comment: какое SQL(pg \ my \ ms \ ...) и как именно в БД выглядит данная запись? (это строка или массив(тонкий намек на то что нужна ddl таблицы)

Comment: Судя по синтаксису шаблона - MySQL. Тогда тупо `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, cat_id)`. PS. При чём тут PDO и PHP?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков в первом предложени я написал вид, я ведь не написал массив.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Хотя правильнее будет нормализовать данные и избавиться от CSV.

Comment: @Владимир вы не написали ничего кроме "хранится в таком виде", гадать по кофейной гуще не приучен, массивы записываются через запятую, csv - тоже, значит как минимум под ваше "хранится в таком виде" подходит как минимум посгревый массив, и запись строки с разделителем запятая, обрабатываются эти ситуации по разному....

Comment: @Akina не сработал вариант. Выводит пустоту. У меня просто в строку хранится в базе ID категорий через запятую.

Comment: Покажите ТОЧНОЕ значение в поле (уж не напихали ли туда после запятых пробелов, типа "так красивше"?). Ну и не экономьте переменные - соберите запрос в отдельную переменную, которую в следующем операторе используйте для подготовки запроса. И покажите, что собралось в переменной.